# Dimensional Model for Employee Turnover

Tags: mdx, dimensional-modeling

I am trying to determine the best way to model the scenario of employee turnover for a Dimensional Model. I am not sure if its best to include the Termination_Count and Headcount in the same measure.

I currently have a headcount measure with both termed and headcount:

```
**Headcount Measure:**
Employee_id
Department
Employee_count
Termed_count
Month
```

So each individual employee will have a row created for them if they are active during the month or if they are terminated during the month.

How have other people worked with employee turnover issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't track Headcount and Turnover in the same table, they have different grains.

- Headcount: being a semi-aditive measure you need a snapshot fact table counting employees per department, salary level, bureau and whatever other dimensions you need. It should store these values once per day;
- Turnover: have a Hire/Fire transaction table with three measures: employees_hired (0/1), employees_fired (0.1) and net_employee_variation (=1/0/+1). On the employee dimension you can have a "date_hired" and "date_left_ as attributes to allow, for example, counting time between the two events.

But you shouldn't mix what is a transaction fact table with a snapshot fact table.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I can see how I am mixing grains which is bad practice. I like the  Hire / Fire / Variance grain.  However I'm still puzzled how to calculate turnover if the measures I need for turnover are in two separate cubes. I would need  turnover.employees_fires / headcount.employee_count. I've read about virtual cubes and maybe that is how to calculate turnover?

Comment: Be careful with virtual cubes. They don't solve every single problem when combining different cubes. In this particular case, the question isn't even well defined. Turnover for March = employees fired in March / headcount in March. But... how do you define Headcount in March? Is it the average of the 31 days? The headcount on day 1? On day 31? A virtual cube won't be able to define this properly because the two date dimensions will be in fact very different. I suggest doing that on the report end of things. Query both cubes, combine the results and display the final formula.